# How to make a square grid in latex?

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I want to make the following square grid in latex. Can anyone please help me on this ? .[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4, vertices/.style={draw, fill=black, circle, inner sep=0.5pt}]
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{13}$}] (a) at (1,1) {};
\node[vertices, label=below:{$a_{14}$}] (b) at (5,1) {};
\node[vertices,label=below:{$a_{15}$}] (c) at (18,1) {};
\node[vertices,label=right:{$a_{13}$}] (d) at (22,1) {};
\node[vertices,label=left:{$a_{11}$}] (e) at (1,5) {}; 
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{12}$}] (f) at (5,5) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{16}$}] (g) at (18,5) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{11}$}] (h) at (22,5) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{8}$}] (i) at (1,13) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{10}$}] (j) at (5,13) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{7}$}] (k) at (1,17) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{9}$}] (l) at (5,17) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{2}$}] (m) at (1,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{3}$}] (n) at (5,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{1}$}] (o) at (1,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=above:{$a_{5}$}] (p) at (5,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=above:{$a_{6}$}] (q) at (9,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{4}$}] (r) at (9,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=above:{$a_{20}$}] (s) at (18,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{1}$}] (t) at (22,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{19}$}] (u) at (18,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{2}$}] (v) at (22,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{18}$}] (w) at (18,17) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{7}$}] (x) at (22,17) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{17}$}] (y) at (18,13) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{8}$}] (z) at (22,13) {};
\foreach \to/\from in
{a/b,a/e,e/f,b/f,c/d,c/g,g/h,h/d,k/i, k/l, l/j, i/j, k/j, o/m, o/p, o/n, m/n, n/p, m/k, m/l,     l/n, p/q, p/r, q/r, r/n, s/u, s/t, u/v, t/v, s/v, u/w,v/x, w/x, u/x, w/y, x/z, y/z, z/w, e/b, g/d} \draw [-] (\to)--(\from);
\foreach \to/\from in
{b/c,f/g, e/i,j/f, q/s, r/u, l/w, y/g, z/h, j/y} \draw [dashed]     (\to)--     (\from);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code you've got so far. If you're not sure where to start, you might look at `makecell` or Ti*k*Z if you want the power of a full-fledged drawing package.

Comment: I can generate this grid with the vertices using tikzpicture . But i have problem to put the name of triangles in the center.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem showing the grid with the vertices.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  Also, the solution may be dependent on how you are creating the grid.

Comment: @PeterGrill I have added MWE.

Comment: @Amitk: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 3):

There might be easier ways, but I think a Tikz `matrix` is a good approach.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style={
        rectangle,
        minimum size=1.8cm,
        text depth=0.5ex,
        text height=2ex,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
    },
    table nodes/.style 2 args={
        draw=black,
        append after command={
            \pgfextra{\draw (\tikzlastnode.north west) -- (\tikzlastnode.south east) 
                node[midway, anchor=north east, minimum size=7mm] {#1}
                node[midway, anchor=south west, minimum size=7mm] {#2};
            }
        }
    },      
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={   
            basic        
        },
        execute at empty cell={\node{};}
    }
}

\newcommand\dcell[2]{%
    |[table nodes={#1}{#2}]|
}

\newcommand\link[3]{%
    \def\switchrow{row}
    \def\switchcol{col}
    \def\argi{#1}
    \ifx\argi\switchrow
        \draw[gray, dashed] (#2.south east) -- (#3.south west);
        \draw[gray, dashed] (#2.north east) -- (#3.north west);
    \else\ifx\argi\switchcol
        \draw[gray, dashed] (#2.south east) -- (#3.north east);
        \draw[gray, dashed] (#2.south west) -- (#3.north west); 
    \fi
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (m) [table]
{
    \dcell{$A_1$}{$A_2$} & \dcell{$B_1$}{$B_2$} & & & \dcell{$C_1$}{$C_2$} \\
    \dcell{$C_3$}{$C_4$} &   & & & \dcell{$C_9$}{$C_10$} \\
    \dcell{$C_5$}{$C_6$} &   & & & \dcell{}{} \\
                        &   & & &  \\
                        &   & & &  \\
    \dcell{$C_7$}{$C_8$} &   & & & \dcell{}{} \\
};

\link{row}{m-1-2}{m-1-5}
\link{row}{m-3-1}{m-3-5}
\link{row}{m-6-1}{m-6-5}

\link{col}{m-3-1}{m-6-1}
\link{col}{m-3-5}{m-6-5}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alenanno, but i also need to add vertices.

Comment: @AmitK Each cell is a node, called `m-<col>-<row>`, you can use that to reference each node and therefore add the vertices.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate little bit.

Comment: @Amitk The matrix has a name, `\matrix (m)` so `m` is the name of this matrix. Each cell is identified by the row and the column, so the top left cell is `m-1-1` as in `<name matrix>-<column number>-<row number>`. The fifth cell in the second row is `m-2-5`, and so on.

Comment: See the [PGF/Tikz manual](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), section **20. Matrices and alignment**, page 305.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your code was generated by some program, which makes it harder to modify.  For something such as this, I would recommend you rethink your approach and do the diagram some other way (such as @Alenanno's answer).

Howver, if you insist on doing it this way you can add nodes as follows:

```
%% Redefine the coordinates for readabilty
\coordinate (a2) at (m);
\coordinate (a5) at (p);

\path (a2) -- (a5) node[pos=0.3, text=red]  {$A_1$};
\path (a2) -- (a5) node[pos=0.7, text=blue] {$A_2$};
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4, vertices/.style={draw, fill=black, circle, inner sep=0.5pt}]
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{13}$}] (a) at (1,1) {};
\node[vertices, label=below:{$a_{14}$}] (b) at (5,1) {};
\node[vertices,label=below:{$a_{15}$}] (c) at (18,1) {};
\node[vertices,label=right:{$a_{13}$}] (d) at (22,1) {};
\node[vertices,label=left:{$a_{11}$}] (e) at (1,5) {}; 
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{12}$}] (f) at (5,5) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{16}$}] (g) at (18,5) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{11}$}] (h) at (22,5) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{8}$}] (i) at (1,13) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{10}$}] (j) at (5,13) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{7}$}] (k) at (1,17) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{9}$}] (l) at (5,17) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{2}$}] (m) at (1,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{3}$}] (n) at (5,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{1}$}] (o) at (1,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=above:{$a_{5}$}] (p) at (5,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=above:{$a_{6}$}] (q) at (9,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{4}$}] (r) at (9,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=above:{$a_{20}$}] (s) at (18,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{1}$}] (t) at (22,25) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{19}$}] (u) at (18,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{2}$}] (v) at (22,21) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{18}$}] (w) at (18,17) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{7}$}] (x) at (22,17) {};
\node[vertices, label=left:{$a_{17}$}] (y) at (18,13) {};
\node[vertices, label=right:{$a_{8}$}] (z) at (22,13) {};
\foreach \to/\from in
{a/b,a/e,e/f,b/f,c/d,c/g,g/h,h/d,k/i, k/l, l/j, i/j, k/j, o/m, o/p, o/n, m/n, n/p, m/k, m/l,     l/n, p/q, p/r, q/r, r/n, s/u, s/t, u/v, t/v, s/v, u/w,v/x, w/x, u/x, w/y, x/z, y/z, z/w, e/b, g/d} \draw [-] (\to)--(\from);
\foreach \to/\from in
{b/c,f/g, e/i,j/f, q/s, r/u, l/w, y/g, z/h, j/y} \draw [dashed]     (\to)--     (\from);


%% Redefine the coordinates for readabilty
\coordinate (a2) at (m);
\coordinate (a5) at (p);

\path (a2) -- (a5) node[pos=0.3, text=red]  {$A_1$};
\path (a2) -- (a5) node[pos=0.7, text=blue] {$A_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ peter Grill Thanks. Its working, but here what is the meaning of  m and n in the \coordinate (a2) at (m) and 
\coordinate (a5) at (p); I think its just not the symbol because if i am putting some other alpha bates different from m and n then either they get different position or giving some error.

Comment: @Amitk: I am just providing anohter name for the node, one that makes `\path` more readable. You remove the two `coordinate` calls and replace `(a2)` with `(m)` and `(a5)` with `(p)` if you wish.